# How to query a table, in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know how to query on a model now. Suppose there is a `Question` model:

```
class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = "questions"
    id=Column(...)
    user_id=Column(...)
    ...
```

Now, I can do:

```
question = Session.query(Question).filter_by(user_id=123).one()
```

But, now, I have a table (not a model) `questions`:

```
questions = Table('questions', Base.metadata,
                  Column(id, ...),
                  Column(user_id, ...),
                  ....)
```

How to query it as what I do with models?

```
Session.query(questions).filter_by(user_id=123).one()
```

This will report an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.3-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 851, in filter_by
  for key, value in kwargs.iteritems()]
File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.6.3-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\util.py", line 567, in _entity_descriptor
    desc = entity.class_manager[key]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'class_manager'
```

But:

```
Session.query(questions).all()
```

is OK.

Is `filter_by` only work for models? How can I query on tables?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think it's `Session.query(questions).filter(questions.c.user_id==123).one()`

Comment: Is there any documentation for querying through tables?

Comment: Select is exposed directly on Table; took me a bit to figure out: [Table.select](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select)

Answer (score 11):

You can query tables that were created with the Table constructor using  `Session.query(Base.metadata.tables['myTable']).all()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a late answer, but what the existing ones are missing is the fact that you can both work with [`Sessions`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) and with [`Engines`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) & [`Connections`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) and that **you do not need to work with a Session if you defined [`sqlalchemy.schema.Table`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) directly**.

But **when should you use a Session, and when a Connection?**

The [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html) has the following to say regarding this:

> Its important to note that when using the SQLAlchemy ORM, these objects [*Engines and Connections*] are not generally accessed; instead, the Session object is used as the interface to the database. However, for applications that are built around direct usage of textual SQL statements and/or SQL expression constructs without involvement by the ORM’s higher level management services, the Engine and Connection are king (and queen?)

In short:

If you are using the ORM (so you write python classes for you data models), you will work with a Session. If you are directly defining Tables, then you don't need to involve any ORM (and related management services) and can work directly with a Connection.

So, **how would working with a Connection look like?**:

Here is a simple example, adapted from [the docs about connections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#using-transactions) that also **answers your question about how to query a table**:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pw@localhost:5432/mydatabase')

# Assuming questions is a sqlalchemy.schema.Table instance

with engine.begin() as connection:
    query = questions.select().where(
        questions.c.user_id == 1)
    q1 = connection.execute(query).fetch_one()
```

See also the docs about [`sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select) for more info.